# having trouble using facebook omniauth

Tags: ruby, facebook, sinatra

i'm trying to authenticate with facebook i have a sinatra app working correctly with twitter.

app.rb

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :twitter, 'xxx', 'yyy'
provider :facebook, 'xxx', 'yyy', :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:9393/auth/facebook'
end
```

i'm referencing the facebook link in my view like,

```
     %a{:href=>"/auth/twitter"} Sign In To Twitter
     %a{:href=>"/auth/facebook"} Sign In To Facebook
```

and i'm being returned

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=268504329935589&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A9393%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&state=a88cbf5f83b2faeac173f23138440cddf48cd5faf0039fe6&scope=email

which looks like

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application      configuration.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 191
   }
}
```

as far as I can tell, my settings look correct.  many posts exist about this issue being tied to facebook and the apps registered url.

on facebook, this app is registered as

```
Site URL
http://localhost:9393/
Site Domain
http://localhost:9393/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i actually found the answer,

`App Domains: localhost/`
and 
`Website with Facebook Login: http://localhost:9393/?`

the `/?` on the localhost (website w fb login) is the important detail

Answer (score 0):

try App Domains: `http://localhost/`

its working for me in rails

```
Site URL:    http://localhost:3000/

App Domains: http://localhost/
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually register a dev app in facebook and add the redirect_uri to my hosts file. Usually something like:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.mycoolapp.com
```